# nuxt.js hot-reload is slow

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to know if it is normal that nuxt takes 2 or 3 seconds to make the hot reload changes?
For example with Gatsby the Hot Reloads are instantaneous. I missed something?

Here is my nuxt build config:

```
build: {
    parallel: true,
    cache: true,
    extractCSS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    optimizeCSS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    transpile: ['vue-intersect'],
},
```

Comment: If you disable parallel and transpile, the speed ​​is increased?
Can you provide us your modules session and buildModules and plugins too?
your build have something else? Verify if you have a property called components: true. If the components is true, you will import all pages and components every reload.

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren I have disabled parallel and transpile but it's the same speed :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your problem is because you have a property *components* setted as *true*.

- Nuxt.js 2.13+ can scan and auto import your components. But by default this option in setted with false. You don't need set it to true.

When set to true or using an object, it will include the nuxt/components dependencies and auto import your components (defined in ~/components) when you use them in your templates.

```
...
// change to false, or remove this config.
components: true
...
```

Only set to true if you know why you need this property as true.
So you can find more about this, in the Nuxt Docs https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components and in the Github docs https://github.com/nuxt/components.

Comment: thanks it's that but, now I have to create all the component imports.

Comment: yeh, you need, but think this cenario: You have one component, and inside this component you have a lot of child component. in this case, you dont need import all the child component in the project context, you need import only the parent component. For a small projects this maybe doesn't matter, but when you have a many many child, subchild component, this is the best way to do it. Nice thats work for you. I'm happy to help you.

Comment: Wow thanks, my builds were taking around 20-30 seconds on each hot reload. After changing components to false it takes less than one second !

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to report that after manually importing about 300 components in approximately 40 pages for about 15 hours, the HMR (Hot Module Replacement) is slower. It has added approximately 100ms on an M1 computer and around 200-300ms on an Intel computer. Therefore, setting "components: false" does not make the hot reload faster.